# How to use Mockito to test SOAP messages?

Tags: java, soap, junit, mockito

I'm fairly new to Mockito, and figured I would try to use it to test a SOAP Handler.  However, this is turning out to be a much more painful than I would have expected/desired.

I'm looking to validate that my handler is able to extract the messageID in the header of a SOAPMessage.  However, from the handler, the only way to get to the header is via the context/message/part/envelope/header.  Using Mockito my solution was to mock my SOAPMessage, meant creating each individual object, and stubbing the method.

I can only imagine that there is an easier/cleaner way of accomplishing this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UUIDHandlerTest {

    @Mock private SOAPMessage message;
    @Mock private SOAPEnvelope envelope;
    @Mock private SOAPHeader header;
    @Mock private SOAPPart part;

    @Mock
    private SOAPMessageContext context;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws SOAPException{
        when( context.getMessage()).thenReturn(message);
        when( message.getSOAPPart()).thenReturn(part);
        when( part.getEnvelope()).thenReturn(envelope);
        when( envelope.getHeader()).thenReturn(header);
    }


    @Test
    public void testHandleInboundMessage() {
        when( context.get(SOAPMessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)).thenReturn(false);

        when(header.getElementsByTagName(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<NodeList>() {
            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see org.mockito.stubbing.Answer#answer(org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock)
             */
            @Override
            public NodeList answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(new String("<wsa:MessageID>messageId</wsa:MessageID>").getBytes()));

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return doc.getElementsByTagName("wsa:MessageID");
            }

        });


        // call the test class
        new UUIDHandler().handleMessage(context);

        // check the MDC value
        assertEquals("messageId", MDC.get(LoggerConstants.DC_PROPERTY_MESSAGE_ID));
    }
}
```

Like I said, it works, but it looks like a very ugly/heavy weight solution.

Is there anyway to do this easier/cleaner?

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    SOAPMessageContext context = 
            mock(SOAPMessageContext.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    when(context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().
            getHeader().getElementsByTagName(anyString())).
            then(...);
```

Please also pay attention to the notes on using deep stubs in the mockito documentation.
http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS

Annotation style:

```
    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) SOAPMessageContext context;
```

Comment: According to the docs, however, using RETURN_DEEP_STUBS should be avoided as much as possible.  In which case, I guess the question becomes, what is a good methodology to perform this type of test?  @time4tea seems to indicate it makes more sense to create a real SOAPMessage, but my whole concept of using Mocks is to avoid needing to create a complicated structure just for testing.  Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Seriously - don't do this. You will end up with code you don't understand, that is very brittle, and that tests the implementation of everything, not just your code. Consider using a real SOAP request (if it is possible to construct one), or even creating a server that returns a known bit of xml, and check that your class extracts the right bit of information from it.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late here, but I prefer spawning a working Endpoint which proxies a mockito mock. This lets me test the whole stack, including interceptors and/or handlers, which should be helpful for your use-case.

I've put up a simple JUnit Rule which simplifies things somewhat [here](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf). The resulting test-cases should be small and clean. I recommend loading test XML responses directly from XML files, because that is faster and more simple to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mock things like this.

Listen to the code... its telling you that this is not the right way to do it.

Rather, just create a (real) message that has some known data in it, and assert that your code does the right stuff with it.

e.g.

MessageIdExtractor extractor = new MessageIdExtractor(); // <- class you are testing

String expectedMessageId = "xxxxxx";

Message m = new SOAPMessage( ).setMessageId(expectedMessageId);

assertThat(extractor.extractIdFrom(m), equalTo(expectedMessageId));

Comment: Sure - except that it isn't that easy to create the SOAPMessage, and consequently, was looking for a way to do it using a mock object instead.